# Can I remove only selected history and form autofill data from Chrome on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I want to do things like remove all form autofill data except that from my banks and a few other sites. I'd also like to be able to remove all my Reddit history, for example.

Using the GUI in Chrome, I can remove all history, or I can click each entry individually - way too time consuming. I can also remove all of my autofill data, or none of it.

I understand that Chrome keeps things in an SQLite database. Can I connect to that somehow to remove thing using SQL queries? Or perhaps there is an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with Chrome internal relational databases could make your browser act strangely. Backup before you start deleting things.

That information is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`, assuming `Default` is your profile folder.

There's a `sqlite3` command line tool that can open the files containing the login and history data. In the SQLite console, `.tables` lists the tables and `.dump` creates a data dump. Otherwise, it accepts SQLite SQL.

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History
sqlite> delete from urls;
sqlite> delete from visits;
sqlite> .quit

sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Login\ Data
sqlite> delete from logins;
sqlite> .quit
```

Note that the actual logins are stored in your systemwide keychain. Open *Keychain Access* to view its entries.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's good for the history although the structure of the autofill (Web Data database) is complicated enough that breakage is likely. Have a +1 for now I'll see if anyone has an extension which can help with the autofill stuff.